# I have work at Python saving dict to dataframe

Tags: python, xcode, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

[image: enter description here]

I have a dictionary dataframe that includes 4 keys. I'm trying to export each key to dataframe by using the following code:

```
for key in AllDict_WC:
    TempDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(AllDict_WC[key],orient='index')
    TempDF.to_csv("C:\\Users\\iaqurban/Desktop\\HW2\\WC.csv",sheet_name = "%s""%key")
```

Any ideas?

At line 2 I got the following prompt:

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Can you please give an example/file of your data so your error is reproducible? Additionally, what have you tried to resolve this issue thus far?

Comment: Please include the full traceback. And format it as a code block, not as quoted text, for clarity.

Comment: I'm storing data file in dictionaries. the file has Stress period (SP), I have stored each SP in Key inside the dictionary. I need to store each key in CSV.
This code I have stored each SP into key:
for sp in range(1,5):   
    for row in range(1,613):
        TempRow = f.readline().split()
        Dict[row] = TempRow
        WC_Temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dict,orient='index')
        AllDict_WC[sp] = WC_Temp
then I used:
    for key, value in AllDict_WC:
        TempDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(AllDict_WC[key],orient='index')
        TempDF.to_csv("WC.csv",sheet_name = "%s""%key")